# Visual Studio how to disable VS Output Window's auto scrolling to bottom during Android/Xamarin debug run?

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, logcat

I am losing my mind ...wondering how could the following behaviour be the shipped default user experience in Visual Studio where all technologies involved are Microsoft-made:

- use microsoft visual studio (2019)
- use microsoft Xamarin.Forms to make an app
- run the app in debug mode to see updates in the VS Output window
- every new line that comes in through logcat from my phone to VS, force auto-scrolls Visual Studio's builtin Output window to the bottom and there's no way to stop it?!

I have to either: 1. stop running the app and read the output. Or 2. futilely wrestle with the damn scrollbar and fight Visual Studio to try to maintain the output window's scroll on a specific position enough moments to read anything.

How did this get past any internal QA for Xamarin? Did they ever try to, you know, make an app? Am I blind? Is there an easy way to stop auto scrolling? Why isn't it enabled by default? The default behavior should be: if the scrollbar is all the way to the bottom, then auto-scroll, sure. But if the scrollbar has been moved by the user, then stop auto-scrolling for the love of god! (this is common sense in many other software)

Also, there's no button on the Output window that locks the scrolling.

Comment: We can try to use logcat to filter log in Android device Monitor, it will not auto scrolling to bottom during Android/Xamarin/ADB/Logcat debug run. Please see this screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/7VTLguX

Comment: Did you try to use logcat the in the  Android device Monitor?

Comment: Yes I know I can use logcat and even filter logcat with some degree of success. But logcat is not visual studio. All I want is to be able to lock a scrollbar in a visual studio window --- is that so much to ask that I need to use separate software? :)

Comment: No, Visual studio have this function, please click the icon like this thread,  https://imgur.com/a/CFjp9wa

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a hack not a solution, but it works:
Just Ctrl+F anything in the Output window. As long as and while this is active / has found something, the auto-scrolling will be locked/stopped. (and you can still use the scrollbar manually)

So the functionality IS already in VS. Just MS didn't bother to add a scroll lock button for it, or have a manual scrolling override. Microsoft has this lovely track record of insistently not using their own products in a way that actual human beings (read: not imaginary simple target personas) will definitely need to use them.

Release a Microsoft dev environment that can't have a pausable (readable) Output window? Microsoft: Sure, why not? We don't see the problem here. **Why would you ever want to read the output of your application?** What an edge case!

Comment: Not seeing how this would increase shareholder value.  The purpose of a corporation is to return as much profit as possible to the shareholders.  MS seems to be pretty clear about that point.

Comment: While funny, @ kejster's answer is THE answer and should be accepted as such

Answer (score 10):

Try placing the caret (in the Output window) somewhere other than at the bottom.
If I click somewhere in the output other than at the very end, Visual Studio will stop scrolling to the bottom.
I haven't tried it with an Android/Xamarin project, but I assume the output window behaves the same for all project types.

Comment: Omg this is extremely bad ux hidden behaviour! (but it sorta works! thanks!) I mean, it's a read-only OUTPUT window, which doesn't display a caret by default, with a visual language that doesn't match any other window in the program which has a caret. So why would a user ever imagine that 1). it would have a caret, and 2). you should click to move the caret but not on the bottom. ..But if it looses focus or gets refreshed somehow, it resets the caret and thus auto-scrolls again

Answer (score 6):

Place your cursor in output window then

autoscroll on `Ctrl+End`

autoscroll off `Ctrl+Home`

Comment: but if that window looses focus / caret gets reset by some process/function of VS, then it auto-scrolls again and you loose your place, right?

Comment: @Spectraljump yes it seems that you have to that each time you build.